# typescript type definiton - interface refers to a type but is used as value

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
export interface Chapter {
    title: string,
    path: string
}

export type TableOfContents: Chapter[]
```

But I am getting the following error:

> [ts] 'Chapter' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here. [2693]

I would like to export the interface Chapter, and then the type TableOfContents which is an array of chapters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a type alias you have to use `=` not `:`.

```
export type TableOfContents = Chapter[]
```

You can see the difference [in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20Chapter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20TableOfContentsValid%20%3D%20Chapter%5B%5D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20TableOfContentsInvalid%3A%20Chapter%5B%5D).